# Convert int64 to uint64

Tags: python, numpy

I want to convert an int64 numpy array to a uint64 numpy array, adding 2**63 to the values in the process so that they are still within the valid range allowed by the arrays. So for example if I start from

```
a = np.array([-2**63,2**63-1], dtype=np.int64)
```

I want to end up with

```
np.array([0.,2**64], dtype=np.uint64)
```

Sounds simple at first, but how would you actually do it?

Answer (score 3):

Use [astype()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html) to convert the values to another dtype:

```
import numpy as np
(a+2**63).astype(np.uint64)
# array([                   0, 18446744073709551615], dtype=uint64)
```

Comment: how? NameError: name 'uint64' is not defined. Anything asides from `numpy` you need?

Comment: @Hack-R: `uint64` should have been `np.uint64`, provided `numpy` is imported using `import numpy as np`. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a real numpy expert, but this:

```
>>> a = np.array([-2**63,2**63-1], dtype=np.int64)
>>> b = np.array([x+2**63 for x in a], dtype=np.uint64)
>>> b
array([                   0, 18446744073709551615], dtype=uint64)
```

works for me with Python 2.6 and numpy 1.3.0

I assume you meant `2**64-1`, not `2**64`, in your expected output, since `2**64` won't fit in a uint64. (18446744073709551615 is `2**64-1`)